# Trouble Writing My First Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

So here is my Makefile:

```
    # My First Makefile
    HEADERS = stdio.h

    all: main.o input.o output.o
             cc -o all main.o input.o output.o

    main.o: main.c $(HEADERS)
             cc -c main.c -o main.o

    input.o: input.c $(HEADERS)
             cc -c input.c -o input.o
    output.o: output.c $(HEADERS)
             cc -c output.c -o output.o


    clean:
           -rm -f *.o
           -rm -f all
```

And below is input.c:

```
 #ifndef __STDIO_H__
 #define __STDIO_H__

 #include <stdio.h>

 void getChar()
 {

    getchar();

 }


 #endif
```

Below is output.c:

```
 #ifndef __STDIO_H__
 #define __STDIO_H__

 #include <stdio.h>

 void putChar(char c)
 {

    putchar(c);

 }

 #endif
```

Below is main.c:

```
#ifndef __STDIO_H__
#define __STDIO_H__
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char c;  
   while ((c = etChar()) != '\n')
   {
      putChar(c);
   }


}

#endif
```

Yet whenever I press "make" command in Terminal,

I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `stdio.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.
```

cc refers to clang

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

I was trying to get used to $(ARGS) by using $(HEADERS)

but it seems that the clang compiler does not accept this.

Do you think I should use gcc instead?

Comment: You don't need include guards in the file where you include `stdio.h`; these are in `stdio.h` itself. You use them in your *own* header files, or use `#pragma once`. Get rid of them here, they're pointless.

Comment: You don't *press* make, you *type* make. and clang doesn't process your makefile, the separate (from your compiler suite) command `make` does. If you want clang only, you can define a variable `CC` by the path to clang and use `$(CC)` in the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unnecessary to write **stdio.h** in your Makefile. GCC will automatically search it in DEFAULT PATH (/usr/include, ....). Write header files as targes in Makefile only if you use your own header files.

```
# Makefile

# define CC
CC := gcc

# define final targets
TARGETS := main

# just trigger $(TARGETS)
all: $(TARGETS)

# build main from main.o, input.o, output.o
main: main.o input.o output.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

# build main.o/input.o/output.c from main.c/input.c/output.c
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

# trigger $(TARGETS), then run ./main
run: $(TARGETS)
    ./main

clean:
    -rm $(TARGETS)
    -rm *.o

# define targets which are not bound to file
.PHONY: all clean run
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

"make" will look for stdio.h in the current directory, and is complaining that the header is not found.

Just to fix this, you should mention the full path where stdio.h is located, for example:

HEADERS = /usr/include/stdio.h

Ideally, if you want to check for the presence of standard headers like stdio.h, you should use tools like automake and autoconf, which generate the Makefile automatically. Here's a link which points to the autoconf documentation:
https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html